# Веб браузер в полно экранном режиме с элементами управления

Tags: javascript, консоль, браузер

Подскажите пожалуйста Веб браузер в полно экранном режиме (f11) с элементами управления только назад, обновить вперед. Подходит любой браузер но если это можно сделать как то в хроме то будет лучше.
Проблема в том что  нужна для киоска типо киви, и прочее терминалы (сенсор). нет клавиатуры и мышки палец только

Comment: Совсем непонятно (

Comment: смотрите нажимаешь на браузере f11 и откромсать вкладка в полноэкранном режиме. Там вообще нет элементы управления типо назад, вперед, обновить. Вот хочется добавить в  полноэкранном режиме эти элементы управления

Answer (score 0):

Общие элементы управления страницей и историей в полноэкранном режиме можно разве что полифильнуть самостоятельно. Сделайте кнопки, которые будут отображаться в случае изменения режима на полноэкранный (есть соответствующее событие). Грубо говоря:

```
document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', () => {
  if (document.fullscreenElement) {
document.getElementById('fullscreen_backBut').style.setProperty('display', 'block');
document.getElementById('fullscreen_forwardBut').style.setProperty('display', 'block');
document.getElementById('fullscreen_reloadBut').style.setProperty('display', 'block');
  }
  else {
document.getElementById('fullscreen_backBut').style.setProperty('display', 'none');
document.getElementById('fullscreen_forwardBut').style.setProperty('display', 'none');
document.getElementById('fullscreen_reloadBut').style.setProperty('display', 'none');
  };
});
```

Переход вперёд по истории осуществляется методом `history.forward()`, назад - `history.back()`. Перезагрузка страницы - `location.reload()`. Прикручиваете это к обработчикам кликов по вашим кнопкам и готово.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но дело в том что мне надо в любом сайте такие кнопки а не только где я могу править код ) например открыл гугл и нажал f11 и там эти кнопки )

Comment: Я бы не сказал тогда, что это вопрос по теме SO, но можете поискать расширения для встраивания собственного жс/ксс кода в страницы. Пропишите там добавление на сайты этих кнопок и их скрытие/открытие по скринченджу